# My dataframe is having a lot of json type columns and i want to normalize it

Tags: json, python-3.x, dataframe

My `dataframe` is having a lot of json type columns. I want to work with the attributes of those json columns. So i want to normalize the dataset for making the `dataframe` free of json formats.

How do i do it?

I tried `json_normalize`.

```
workflow_od_data = json_normalize(data = workflow_od, 
                            record_path =workflow_od['fares_docs'],  
                            meta =[ 'compartment', 'dep_date_end', 'dep_date_start','destination','origin','pos'])
```

[image: This is how my data looks]